# Android cannot find abc_screen_simple.xml

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

App sporadic can not find the `res/layout/abc_screen_xml` bug,
this file is used as `SubDecor`, in `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9#createSubDecor()`.

This is the stack trace collected by the Fabric.

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/abc_screen_simple.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c0015
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1243)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2172)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1170)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.keke.common.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:166)
       at com.keke.common.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:162)
       at com.keke.common.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:158)
       at com.keke.app.splash.SplashActivity.onCreateTask(SplashActivity.java:102)
       at com.keke.common.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:55)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

I analyzed for a long time, I didn't find the cause and solution that caused the problem.

Comment: Try `Build > Clean project`

Comment: @Chanjung Kim Can guarantee that there is no cache when building the project

Comment: Try `adb uninstall YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`. And please update with all the related parts of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By analyzing the historical version, I found the cause of the problem! Is my encryption of the apk res folder causing this layout to fail decryption!

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest appcompat library by haveing following line app build.gradle.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I am using `appcompat-v7:28.0.0`

Comment: Check if you have added following dependency in app build.gradle.                              com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0

Comment: Yes, I used `appcompat-v7:28.0.0`

Comment: appcompat is dependent on support library. Add this in build.gradle.                                                                com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is issue in how you implemented and using it, can you please share your **xml file** and **java file** in which you using it.

It can small problem like **wrong file names or syntax issue**, i **can not really say** clearly until you **share your java and xml file.**